# How to get recent used applications pragmatically?

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo, android-recents

I am trying to implement the add recently opened application in my application. I am trying to do with the [getRunningAppProcess()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses()) but it gives me only my application details. Also, tried with the [getSystemService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)), but didn't get any lead. Found the upvote solution of UsageStats, it also gives only my application details.

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -5);

        final List<UsageStats> stats =
                mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST,
                        cal.getTimeInMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (stats == null) {
            return;
        }

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i advice you to check **[App usage statistics](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics)** API on github , it will allow you to collect statistics related to usage of the applications. it provides more detailed usage information than the deprecated `getRecentTasks()` method.